# python sum iterable variable

Tags: python, sum, iterable

very simple question, I think.
I have multiple dataframes, that I'm summing them to obtain a result, ex :

```
df1 = 272.6692725
df2 = 224.876735
df3 = 262.70736
df4 = 329.1992858333333
df5 = 542.3639916666667
```

And like it for a long serie.
I just want to sum all this in another variable, like "total = ..."

So I tried something like :

```
for x in range(0,300):
    x +=1
    total = sum(globals()[f"df{x}"])
```

But I have "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable".
I think I don't have a good approach but can't figure it out.

Comment: You don't seem to have multiple dataframes, you have multiple `float` variables. And you should just put them in a list instead of having them in separate variables, then you can call `sum()` on the list.

Comment: That's a synthesis, my df are timeseries and the exact format of it would be df1.mean() in a case and [df1][df1>0].sum() in an other case, with a result of a unique float. I didn't precise that to keep focus on the problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum for example always that x value to the total you can just do

```
for x in range(300): #Dont need to mention 0 
    total += x # Your x is already being incremented
```

If that is not what you want, I am sorry. It was what I interpreted

Comment: Can't "+1" the answer because it seem that I'm too young user of stackoverflow, but that the way I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to increment x since it's a for loop. I would advise you to save your summed values into a list, then calling `sum(np.array(your_list))`

Comment: I tried to avoid list to keep it as simple as possible (for me ;-) thanks